# How to create table using external key word in hive

Tags: hive

I want to process the data in `hdfs` , i am trying to create table using external keyword then i am getting following error, can you please provide solution for this.

```
hive> create EXTERNAL table samplecv(id INT, name STRING)
      row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
     with serdeproperties (
        "separatorChar" = "\t",
        "quoteChar"     = "'",
       "escapeChar"    = "\\"
      )   
     LOCATION '/home/siva/jobportal/sample.csv';
```

I am getting following error, can u please provide solution for this

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Parent path is not a directory: /home/siva/jobportal/sample.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please confirm that this path is on HDFS?

More info on the creating external tables in Hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables

Comment: Exactly. That route looks like a local directory, not like an HDFS directory. As Abhijeet said, validate that. If the data is in local, put it in the HDFS with "hdfs dfs -put" and point the external table to a directory. After that "LOAD" the file in the table and will be moved to the EXTERNAL directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for XML parsing serde in hive ---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE XYZ(
X STRING, 
Y STRING, 
Z ARRAY<STRING>
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.X"="/XX/@X",
"column.xpath.Y"="/YY/@Y"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/XXX' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<xml start",
"xmlinput.end"="</xml end>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Hive only allows you to set a *directory* as a partition location while adding a partition. What you are trying to do here is to set a *file* as partition location. The workaround that I use is to first add a partition with a dummy/non-existent directory (Hive doesn't demand the directory exist while it's being set as a partition location) and then use *alter table  partition  set location*  to change the partition location to your desired file. Surprisingly, Hive doesn't force the location to be a directory while setting the location of an existing partition the way it does while adding a new partition. So in your case, it will look like -

```
alter table samplecv add partition (id='11', name='somename') location '/home/siva/jobportal/somedirectory'
alter table samplecv partition (id='11', name='somename') set location '/home/siva/jobportal/sample.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive always expect directory name in Location path instead of file name.

create your file inside a directory for example inside /home/siva/jobportal/sample/sample.csv and then try running below command to create your hive table.

```
create EXTERNAL table samplecv(id INT, name STRING)
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
with serdeproperties (
"separatorChar" = "\t",
"quoteChar"     = "'",
"escapeChar"    = "\\"
)   
LOCATION '/home/siva/jobportal/sample';
```

In case if you get any error just put your file in hdfs and try, it should work.